# Why do i get this error message for my SQL project in python?

Tags: python, sql, mariadb

mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

I am trying to add some data into an SQL database for a project and I am met with this error message? [Picture of the error message in the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHoQq.png)Does anyone have any answers?

```
def inputValues():
        supplierValue=choice.get()
        productValue=name.get()
        weightValue=weight.get()
        
        print (supplierValue,productValue,weightValue)

        query_vals = (supplierValue,productValue,weightValue)
        command_handler.execute("INSERT INTO stock(Supplier,Product,Weight)")
        db.commit()
```

I am trying to enter some values into a database. I have created the database in php admin and can show a picture of how I've formatted it.[Image of the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3vbZ.png) I get an error message which I am unsure how to deal with.

Comment: You're missing the part of the query where it says the values to be inserted...

Comment: What is wrong with the error message? It tells you to check the manual -> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html

Answer (score 1):

The INSERT query is supposed to specify the column names and values to be inserted, like this:

```
INSERT INTO stock(Supplier,Product,Weight) VALUES ('ACME Corp', 'Road Runner Decoy', 5.5)
```

But your query looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO stock(Supplier,Product,Weight)
```

Your query is missing the `VALUES ...` part.

Comment: Thank you, I realise that now and so the problem is fixed.